# Nodejs receiving unkown image encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, visual-studio-code, encoding

When calling the endpoint to receive an image on postman I receive the image visually as you can see below : [image]

However, when I call it from Visual Studio Code I receive this format: [image]

What type of encoding is Visual Studio Code showing me ?

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio code, what you see is the **Image Buffer**

however, you use the **Base64** for light size files, max size **~50 -60 MB**